# How to solve this linking problem in Makefile?

Tags: linker, makefile

Here's my Makefile:

```
DIR=..
ARG=$(QUERY_STRING)

MAIN=main

SRC_DIR=$(DIR)/src
BIN_DIR=$(DIR)/bin
INC_DIR=$(DIR)/inc
LIB_DIR=$(DIR)/lib

LIBS=markdown

all: $(MAIN) exec


$(MAIN): $(MAIN).o
    $(LD) $^ -L $(LIB_DIR) -l $(LIBS) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@

$(MAIN).o: $(SRC_DIR)/$(MAIN).c
    $(CC) $^ -I $(INC_DIR) -o $@

exec:
    $(BIN_DIR)/$(MAIN) $(ARG)

clean:
    rm -f *.o core.* $(BIN)/$(MAIN)
```

It's clearly defined how my project is organized, so I will not explain it. It does compile without any problems, but on binary execution `$(BIN_DIR)/$(MAIN)` the following error appears:

```
../bin/main: error while loading shared libraries: rintf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [exec] Error 127
```

What library does `rintf` belong? I tried to link `-lc` too, but that doesn't solves the problem.

Is there something wrong with my `Makefile`? Or should I link something extra to `$(MAIN)`?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should essentially never link a program by invoking `ld` directly; always use your compiler to do the linking.  It passes all sorts of extra arguments to `ld` to make things work.  Replace the `$(LD)` with `$(CC)`.  Do that regardless of whether it actually fixes your problem or not.

'Tis odd that you are not getting the name of the shared object specified in the error message.

This manual page for [rintf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rintf) indicates that it is declared in `<math.h>`; most likely, you need to add the maths library to the link line: `-lm`.

I would rewrite some of your makefile:

```
LIB1    = -lmarkdown
LIB2    = -lm
LIBS    = $(LIB1) $(LIB2)
LDFLAGS = -L $(LIB_DIR)

...

$(MAIN): $(MAIN).o
    $(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@
```

Comment: +1. Also, the `all: $(MAIN) exec` rule is unwise; Make does not promise to build a target's prerequisites in order left-to-right. Better: `all: exec` and `exec: $(MAIN)`.

Comment: @Beta: yes, you're right.  Personally, I don't particularly like makefiles that automatically execute programs that have been built, but that could be an old fogey thinking.  It depends, in part, on what the execution does, I suppose; unit test or regression test makes sense - and that's likely what it is here.  And I have plenty of counter-examples from work done in the office.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this error appears when the linker is not able to find the needed shared object (.so file).I am assuming Linux platform.

In Linux OS, you can search for the file using: `find`, or `locate`. If you can find the .so file, try to update the linker cache using `ldconfig`. If it did not work, check the linker configuration files under `/etc/ld.conf.d/` to see if the library path is included. If you changed the configuration, don't forget to update the cache again!